# Is it OK to use Jquery UI for positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am planning to use the Jquery UI for positioning ..is it OK or should I got the regular height and width and offset to do the positioning.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the positioning is not dynamic then do all your positioning in your style sheet.

But if the positioning is dynamic (changes based on what is loaded) then use jQuery to position accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK, IMHO but a better way might be to go the traditional `div` and `css` route.

The issue with jQuery might be one of resolutions and different browsers.  Not entirely sure on that.

Personally I would use `CSS` where I could and leave jQuery to the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is an extension of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). jQuery is a JavaScript wrapper. If it is not necessary, then omitting JavaScript is compatible with more browsers. Some statistics say about 6-7%+ users do not use JavaScript.

That being said, you would not use jQuery UI for positioning, you would use jQuery; all that would do is just add CSS anyway to the HTML node.